# Setup DHCP manual on ubuntu server

Tags: server, 18.04

Today I installed Ubuntu 18.04 server on my computer, I skipped the fourth step of the installation process, now I've to set up static IP, can I do this like this picture below?

[image]

Comment: see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html.en-CA#ip-addressing)

Answer (score 0):

The installer is removed after installation is complete there is no (simple) way to invoke the wizard again. There used to be a package called `base-config` that you could use `dpkg-reconfigure` with, but it was removed and now you have to modify `/etc/network/interfaces` manually. See `man interfaces` for how that works.

Comment: ubuntu 18.04 does not use `/etc/network/interfaces`, it uses netplan (at least by default).